# ReferenceArrayInput and SelectArrayInput not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

Hope someone can help me with this.
I want to create a notification that has title, message, and an array of user id's (for specific notifications). I use `ReferenceArrayInput` and `SelectArrayInput` to achieve this functionality, but it doesn't work as expected.

In `App.jsx`

```
<Admin authClient={authClient(feathersClient, authClientOptions)}
       restClient={restClient(feathersClient, options)}>
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} options={{label: 'Usuarios'}} icon={UsersIcon}/>
        <Resource name="notifications" list={NotificationsList} create={NotificationsCreate} options={{label: 'Notificaciones'}} icon={NotificationIcon}/>
</Admin>
```

In `Notifications/create.jsx`

```
<Create title="Crear notificación" {...this.props}>
     <SimpleForm>
         <TextInput source="title" label="Título"/>
         <TextInput source="message" label="Mensaje" />
         <ReferenceArrayInput source="recipients" reference="users" label="Usuarios">
             <SelectArrayInput optionText='firstName'/>
         </ReferenceArrayInput>
      </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

When click on the rendered input, it fetches the users correctly, but when clicking a user, it doesn't push the chip to the input.
I don't know why, if the users array from the server is correct, and when I select a user, doesn't add it to the recipients array.

Here is my `package.json` for additional knowledge about the project

```
{
  "name": "gmx-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-on-rest": "^1.3.2",
    "aor-feathers-client": "^0.7.1",
    "feathers-client": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are in a `Create` component, have you try adding the `allowEmpty` prop to the `ReferenceArrayInput` ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I didn't put it here, but `allowEmpty` is in my `ReferenceArrayInput` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the rest of the user GET request ?